# Using Rx to queue operations I don't want executed until particular time?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, threadpool, system.reactive

Summary: I have a web app that executes workflows on business objects and sometimes needs to deliberately wait several seconds or minutes between steps. I'm looking to (perhaps via Rx.NET), improve the execution of these workflows so I do not exhaust the ThreadPool and make the website unresponsive when the system is under heavy load.

A very simplified version of the workflow is:

1. Create an object
2. Load data into it from System A
3. POST this data to System B

If System A is down, my app waits and retries later. The wait time is modeled after GMail's escalating delays in retry: Wait 1 second, double on each subsequent retry (maxing out at 1 hour). The app saves state to the database obsessively so if the whole app blows up, when it restarts it will resume all workflows where it left off.

Currently (please be gentle) each step in the workflow is executed by calling ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to queue up a method that calls Thread.Sleep if necessary for the retry delay described above, then actually executes the step.

If the system is performing well (no errors), it can easily handle all the traffic we throw at it, and the ThreadPool nicely manages parallel execution of all these workflow instances. But if System B is down for a while, retry count and thus delay grows, and pretty soon the ThreadPool is filled with all the sleeping threads, causing the website to become unresponsive to new requests.

Essentially I want to throw all these pending workflows into a queue ordered by (last execution time + desired retry delay). Despite reading a lot about and being excited by Rx, I've never had an opportunity to use it, but it seems like it might be a helpful way to handle this. If Rx can magically manage spitting out these objects when they're ready to fire it seems like it would

1. Greatly simplify and clarify this logic, and
2. Prevent the wasteful use of lots of threads that are just sleeping 99% of the time

Any guidance to an Rx newbie would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just to explain why this is in fact not a good use case for Rx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post on the Rx forums. Pretty handy operator for the kind of problem you want to solve: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/af43b14e-fb00-42d4-8fb1-5c45862f7796/

Rx is a great way to deal with problems like this (and in particular), because you can have your async functions/observables and apply generic operators like the described Retry operator to them.

Comment: Thank you all. I think the final solution is going to take aspects of all these answers, but the RetryWithBackOff approach described in this link seems like the closest starting point.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, I might stick with your current solution, because of this bit:

> The app saves state to the database obsessively so if the whole app blows up, when it restarts it will resume all workflows where it left off.

"Resuming" a pipeline (i.e. `x.Where().Select().Timeout().Bla()`) via deserialization on startup is...tricky.

It's hard to give you a more detailed solution without more info, it might actually work pretty well with Rx if you don't try to model the entire flow, just the transaction bit (i.e. load from A, send to B).

Anyway, the way to solve your thread pool exhaustion is via the System.Threading.Timer class, which tells the thread pool to simply wait until the timeout before queueing a new item.

Comment: Hmm. To be clear I don't serialize/deserialize to manage or resume state. I simply save the object to the database after every attempt to execute a step, incrementing its RetryCount property on failure, resetting it to zero and advancing its ExecutionStep on success. The design accepts that work may execute twice (if it blows up while writing to the db, for example), but guarantees it won't be missed. Does that change your answer?

Comment: No - say you modeled the entire transaction of retrieving all the objects from A and posting them to B, then halfway through sending to B, the server dies. Resuming the pipeline but realizing the objects from A are already posted would be tricky.

Comment: Though in this simple case, you could say the input is the Merge() of unprocessed objects on disk *and* stuff from server A

Comment: Put another way, if state persistence weren't a concern, and I had 10 items I wanted to execute, the first 7 to run ASAP, and the last three 23 seconds, 4 minutes, and 1 hour from now, would I want to use Rx for this? If not, why not, and if so, how? (And many many thanks for your help)

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I'm fine with double-posting in that case. I need to guarantee execution occurred, and will accept double-posting as that consequence.

Comment: Basically, state is either "definitely executed" or "assume it didn't execute"

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely have to adapt:

```
public IDisposable StartProcess<T>(Action<T> load, Action<T> post) where T : new()
{
    return StartProcess(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), new T())
                .Do(load)
                .Subscribe(post);
}

private IObservable<long> StartProcess<T>(TimeSpan span, T obj) where T : new()
{
    Observable
        .Interval(span)
        .OnErrorResumeNext(Observable.Defer(() => StartProcess(IncreaseSpan(span), obj)))
        .Concat(Observable.Defer(() => StartProcess(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), new T())));
}

private TimeSpan IncreaseSpan(TimeSpan span)
{
    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(span.TotalSeconds < 1800? span.TotalSeconds * 2 : 3600);
}
```

Now I'd much rather have load instantiate and fill the object rather than doing it explicitly since functional programming discourages mutability and you may wish `load` to actually go to a database and restore the state like you mentioned.

I wasn't sure if you wanted to preserve the state object in case the call to `post` or `load` crashed and you will need to adapt because currently, it'll preserve the state whether `load` or `post` crashes and will call `load` again without a fresh state if `post` crashes which may definitely not be what you want to do.

I didn't test the code, but Rx is suitable for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. I think this makes the "right" Rx approach clearer to me. Alas, I'm still getting my brain around the Rx way of thinking about composition, but this is very helpful.